# Page results from Azure Application Insights Analytics API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

Is it possible to "page" the results from the Analytics API?

If I use the following Query (via http POST)

```
{
 "query":"customEvents | project customDimensions.FilePath, timestamp 
         | where timestamp > now(-100d) | order by timestamp desc | limit 25"
}
```

I get up to 10,000 results back in one result set. Is there any way to use something similar to the $skip that they have for the events API? Like "SKIP 75 TAKE 25" or something to get the 4th page of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[edit: this answer is now out of date, there has been a `row_number` function added to the query language.  this answer left for historical purposes if anyone runs into strange queries that look like this answer]**

Not *easily*.

If you can use the /events ODATA query path instead of the /query path, that supports paging.  but not really custom queries like you have.

To get something like paging, you need to make a complicated query, and use `summarize` and `makeList` and invent a `rowNum` field in your query, then use `mvexpand` to re-expand the lists and then filter by the `rowNum`.  it's pretty complicated and unintuitive, something like:

```
customEvents 
| project customDimensions.FilePath, timestamp 
| where timestamp > now(-100d) 
| order by timestamp desc 
// squishes things down to 1 row where each column is huge list of values
| summarize filePath=makelist(customDimensions.FilePath, 1000000)
    , timestamp=makelist(timestamp, 1000000)
    // make up a row number, not sure this part is correct
    , rowNum = range(1,count(strcat(filePath,timestamp)),1)
// expands the single rows into real rows
| mvexpand filePath,timestamp,rowNum limit 1000000
| where rowNum > 0 and rowNum <= 100 // you'd change these values to page
```

i believe there's already a request on the appinsights uservoice to support paging operators in the query language.

the other assumption here is that *data isn't changing* in the underlying table while you're doing work.  if new data appears *between your calls*, like

1. give me rows 0-99
2. 50 new rows appear
3. give me rows 100-199

then step 3 is *actually* giving you back 50 duplicate rows that you just got in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

There's a **more correct** way to do this now, using new operators that were added to the query language since my previous answer.

The two operators are `serialize` and `row_number()`.

`serialize` ensures the data is in a shape and order that works with `row_number()`.  Some of the existing operators like `order by` already create serialized data.

there's also `prev()` and `next()` operators that can get the values from previous or next rows in a serialized result.

Comment: I have same requirement to implement pagination. my sample query is below could you please let me how  Ican  implement pagination. CustomEvents | project TimeGenerated,ResourceId,OperationName,OperationVersion,Resource,ResourceGroup,ResourceProvider,SubscriptionId