# Row_number() or other analytical functions possible in appinisghts?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, aiql

I have a pretty simple problem, but I am using appInsights and cant seem to figure out how to replicate row_number() function in aiql or any of the functions (no sense of partition by).

I have pageviews table and I order them by session and timestamp. I would like to add a rown_number column to the set

```
pageViews | where timestamp > ago(14d) | order by session_id, timestamp desc
| extend rn =row_number() partition by session_id
```

Does anyone know if that is possible in aiql

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve? It might be able to do what you want without needing row numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page results from Azure Application Insights Analytics API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371188/page-results-from-azure-application-insights-analytics-api)

Comment: possible duplicate, if the followup question is "how do i use row number to page results"

Comment: I want to order user sessions and sort of do a data flow for each page - where people start browsing and how they explore the website

Answer (score 5):

There's now a better way as there's a support for row_number function. To use it, simply pipe the following statement

...| serialize | extend rn = row_number()

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do it, but it isn't very pretty.

> To get something like paging, you need to make a complicated query, and use `summarize` and `makeList` and invent a `rowNum` field in your query, then use `mvexpand` to re-expand the lists and then filter by the `rowNum`.

from this question about paging, which is generally the question that follows rownum questions: how do I
[Page results from Azure Application Insights Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371188/page-results-from-azure-application-insights-analytics-api)